# How can I get real client IP from Nginx ingress load balancer in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, gke-networking

How can I get **real client IP** from Nginx ingress load balancer in GKE? According to the online resource, I have configured the External Traffic Policy:  Local and added use-proxy-protocol: "true" property also.

But still, I'm seen the GKE node IP/interface in the log, not the real client IP.

My load balancer service ->

```
Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=0.41.2
                          helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-3.10.1
Annotations:              networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: Internal
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       xx.xxx.xx.xx
IPs:                      xx.xx.xxx.xx
LoadBalancer Ingress:     xx.xx.xx.xx
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32118/TCP
Endpoints:                xx.x.xx.xx:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31731/TCP
Endpoints:                xx.x.xx.xxx:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     30515
```

My config map ->

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  access-log-path: /var/log/nginx-logs/access.log
  compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"
  enable-real-ip: "true"
  enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
  error-log-path: /var/log/nginx-logs/error.log
  large-client-header-buffers: 4 64k
  log-format-upstream: $remote_addr - $request_id - [$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for] -
    $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"
    "$http_user_agent" $request_length $request_time [$proxy_upstream_name] $upstream_addr
    $upstream_response_length $upstream_response_time $upstream_status
  proxy-read-timeout: "240"
  proxy-send-timeout: "240"
  real-ip-header: proxy_protocol
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  use-proxy-protocol: "true"
```

Comment: You want to get the actual client IP in your backend serving Pods?

Comment: @GariSingh yes, I want to get the actual client IPs.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the following [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
  enable-real-ip: "true"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: "<pods_cidr>,<services_cidr>,<load_balance_ip>/32"
  use-proxy-protocol: "false"
```

And added the statement `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` on [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) Service that assign the load balance:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
    - appProtocol: https
      name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: <load_balance_ip>
```

I hadn't success. Then, I also tried to configure *ip-masq-agent* with the follow ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ip-masq-agent
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  config: |
    nonMasqueradeCIDRs:
      - <load_balance_ip>/32
      - <pods_cidr>
      - <services_cidr>
    masqLinkLocal: false
    resyncInterval: 30s
```

So, I deleted the DaemonSet *ip-masq-agent* and [gke](/questions/tagged/gke) automatic recreated it.

After that, I got my [gke](/questions/tagged/gke) cluster working as expected.

You can find more information about *ip-masq-agent* on [gke](/questions/tagged/gke) accessing https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent

Answer (score -1):

How are you?

Also you need to set this on Kubernetes spec:

```
externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

For instance,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: example
  ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
```

So you can use those as following in Nginx settings:

```
use-proxy-protocol: "false"
enable-real-ip: "true"
use-forwarded-headers: "true"
proxy-real-ip-cidr: "YOUR-LB-IP/32"
```

**PLUS**

If you want to force HTTPS redirecting, so you can set this as desired in the Nginx settings:

```
force-ssl-redirect: "true"
```

Read futher on https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-parameters#externalTrafficPolicy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).